# Couldn't kill process using process id

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm hosting node application on godaddy server. For that I'm starting node service using `pm2 start` command. After starting the service/process, for every second it's changing process id and couldn't kill the process at all using `kill -9 <pid>`. And also after some time it shows status as errored.

Kindly someone help me kill the process

Comment: What about `killall` ? https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall

Comment: pid is getting changed constantly

Comment: Probably your application keep crashing and pm2 try to restart it.
If you start with pm2 start, why not using pm2 stop or pm2 delete to kill it?

Comment: Thank you I'm new to this so I was not aware of this.

Comment: Yeah, you should take a look at the official document: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/
If you start your script with a name, you can control it easily via that name.
Do not use killall because it can affect other processes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some error with your application. May be you are using Node Process manager which is restart the application everytime it's crashing. That's why you are getting a new PID.

For killing all node processes you can use -

```
killall node
```